# Locked out of login

Tags: login

I have been locked out of my dashboard for over a week now, the error message says in correct details. i have reset my password, but this has not worked.

any advice.

Comment: please specify your Magento version

Comment: Check my answer it will help you if you are using Magento 2 version.

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: Hello not Magento 2...

Comment: @KateWalker, if none of the answers help you, please specify your Magento version in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need direct database access to reset the admin password.

> If you are having troubles and want to reset it to a different password, just run at your sql database:
>
> SELECT * FROM admin_user;
>
> Then, find the username you want to modify in the listing provided - ‘admin’ in this example. Then, to update the password, type:
>
> UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
>
> ‘qX’ would be changed to whatever you want it to be and same goes for ‘password’
>
> You can also do this in phpMyAdmin, find the admin_user field and choose MD5 when updating password.
>
> If you want to add a new admin user, you must not only create a new entry in the table ‘admin_user’, but you also have to insert an entry in the table ‘admin_role’ which has to be associated with the user by the field ‘user_id’.

Source
 - https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14024839#content/view/14024839

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Magento 2 then here is a solution.

Here is how you can unlock and Go to your Magento root folder SSH.

Then Run the following command

> php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME

Or jump into bin directory from Magento root: cd bin/

and then run a command

> php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME

For more detail visit magento official [doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html).